# Class constructor not working?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Code:

**In class header file:**

```
 class Coconuts
{
public:
    Coconuts constructor();

};
```

**In class .cpp file:**

```
     #include "Coconuts.h"
     #include <iostream>
     #include <string>
     using namespace std;


Coconuts::constructor()
{
    cout << "\nYay coconuts are initialized";
};
```

In main():

```
 Coconuts Object1;
```

My program runs without any erros whatsoever, but the constructor isn't initialized and the message
is not displayed. Suggestions, anyone?

Comment: From where did you read that `constructor()` is the name of any class constructor ?

Comment: which book are you following that does not explain this basic stuff?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constructors are not functions named `constructor`. The "name" of a constructor is the name of the class itself. Note that constructors are not normal functions and cannot be directly referenced by name, which is why I put "name" in quotation marks.

Your code should be as follows:

```
//.h
class Coconuts
{
public:
    Coconuts();
};

//.cpp
Coconuts::Coconuts()
{
    cout << "\nYay coconuts are initialized";
};
```

Comment: For completeness, the same applies to destructors.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a constructor, the constuctor is just the name of the class :-

```
 class Coconuts 
 { 
 public:     
    Coconuts();  
 };
```

and

```
Coconuts::Coconuts()  
{      
    cout << "\nYay coconuts are initialized";  
};
```